# Adding a new row to a list

Tags: list, append, row

I have:

```
row1 = [1,'a']  
row2 = [2,'b']
```

I want to create 'allrows' to look like these two rows concatenated together.  In fact, I want to start with an empty list and add rows.
append does not do the job, it just creates a long horizontal list.
How do I create a list or other structure that holds each row as a `ROW`?
For two rows, I want the result to be:

```
[[1,'a']  
 [2,'b']]
```

I am not sure I need the outer brackets, but put them in there assuming the final structure was itself a list, I suppose any other structure that holds these lists, like an "array" of lists, will be fine, as long as I can write out specific rows using:
for line in allrows:
    print line

Thanks!

Comment: first off what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guesing that you code in Python.
List can hold other lists so you can do this

```
allrows = [row1, row2]

for row in allrows: 
    print (row)
```

Output would be

```
[1,'a'] 
[2,'b']
```